# Could you help me with the name of this plant?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, plant-recommendations

This plant started getting dry, but I have no idea what is this plant called so I don't know how to treat it the best way.

[image]

Comment: I think dryness due to soil poverty! Try to find some supplemental solutions contains Potassium, Phosphate and Urea to add it with irrigation water or try to use natural fertilizers such as birds' manure or some dried plants leafs.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a "**Peace Lily**", the common name for "**Spathiphyllum**" which is the plant's genus name. They are a member of the Arum family. I am not sure of the "dry" problem you might be having with your plant, but they are quite easy to care for.  Here are a few links that might help more.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spathiphyllum

https://www.flowerpatchfarmhouse.com/caring-peace-lily-spathiphyllum/

https://www.wikihow.com/Care-for-Peace-Lilies

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a Peace Lily. The damage to the leaves might be from different sources. Either it has too much direct sun light or the water is not enough. It looks a bit damp, if you water it, it should "revive". The brown spots won't go away though. Thr brown spots might also appear from watering with tap water.